Spring kafka @KafkaListener missing several messages
I have KafkaListener
@KafkaListener(
            idIsGroup = false,
            id = "#{T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()}",
            topics = "${kafka.topic}",
            groupId = "OpenDialGroup",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",
            concurrency = "2")
    public void employeeListener(Message message, @Header(value = "RqUID", required = false) String rquid) {
        MDC.put("rquid", "[" + Strings.nullToEmpty(rquid) + "]");
        try {
            log.debug("Received new message {}", message);
            //...
            log.debug("Message processed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error processing user", e);
        }
        finally {
            MDC.clear();
        }
    }

Also config
@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Message> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapAddress());
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        if (kafkaTeamidProperties.getTrustStoreLocation() != null && !kafkaProperties.getTrustStoreLocation().isEmpty()) {
            configProps.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
            configProps.put("ssl.truststore.location", kafkaProperties.getTrustStoreLocation());
            configProps.put("ssl.truststore.password", kafkaProperties.getTrustStorePassword());
            configProps.put("ssl.keystore.location", kafkaProperties.getKeyStoreLocation());
            configProps.put("ssl.key.password", kafkaProperties.getKeyStorePassword());
            configProps.put("ssl.keystore.password", kafkaProperties.getKeyStorePassword());
            configProps.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "");
        }

        JsonDeserializer<TeamIdEmployeeMessage> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Message.class, false);
        deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }

In my topic i have 3 partition.
I have two instasnce of my Spring application runnin on wildfly servers and listening one topic in one consumer group.
When i send 300.000 messages in topic i receive about 115.000.
Iam dont understand where i lost my messages.
If i stopted one instance of my app i receive all messages. Whats wrong with it?

With concurrency = "2" and two application instances you got 4 Kafka consumers for those 3 partition in that consumer group. Still have to work as you explain. Nothing obvious from your config. I suggest to enable DEBUG logging level for the org.springframework.kafka category and investigate those logs on both applications.
